# Не запускается skype в CentOS

Tags: centos, skype, xfce, rhel

Загрузил `skype` с официального сайта, установил следующим образом:

```
$ sudo yum install skypeforlinux-64.rpm
```

Запускаю со значка с рабочего стола, но ничего не происходит. Пробовал запускать из терминала - то же самое, как от пользователя, как и от рута.

В чем может быть проблема?

Система: `RHEL`, `CentOS`, `Xfce`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустил `skypeforlinux` в терминале напрямую из его папки (от пользователя)

```
$ /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
```

и получил следующую ошибку:

> The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /usr/share/skypeforlinux/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.

**Решение:**

```
$ sudo chmod 4755 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/chrome-sandbox
```

---

<sub>См дополнительно: репозиторий со старыми версиями `rpm` пакетов [skype-stable](https://repo.skype.com/rpm/stable/skype-stable.repo)</sub>